# java spark parallelize method parameters

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm writing a test program in java and would like to parallelize a list object.

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local[*]")
      .appName("JavaWordCount")
      .getOrCreate();

System.out.println("hello");
List<String> l = new ArrayList<>(5);
l.add("view.txt");
spark.sparkContext().parallelize(l,1,"test");
```

> The method parallelize(Seq, int, ClassTag) in the type
>   SparkContext is not applicable for the   arguments (List, int,
>   String)

I'm not sure what would be the third parameter - class Tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general when working with Java you should prefer `JavaSparkContext` methods:

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;

JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());

JavaRDD<String> rdd = jsc.parallelize(l, 1);
```

`SparkContext` is intended mostly for Scala usage.

Answer (score 0):

Give you want to parallelize a list of `String`, this should do:

```
ClassTag.apply(String.class)
```